# ASP.NET MVC Get file from virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

For various reasons, in development I occasionally want to intercept a request for, say, ~/MyStyle.css

What I want to do is make the following snippet work:

```
string absFile = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(file);
return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(absFile);
```

This absolute path is absolute for the webserver though, it's not going to map to "C:\whatever". Is there an equivalent method to go to the file system? (Or a `ReadFromVirtualPath` etc.?)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `Server.MapPath()` to get the file system path for a requested application path.

```
string absFile = Server.MapPath(file);
```

or

```
string absFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(file);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the `OpenFile` method on `VirtualPathProvider` to get a Stream pointing at your file

```
var stream = HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.OpenFile(file);
var text = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
```

Generally this approach is preferable since you can now, at a later point implement a `VirtualPathProvider` where, lets say all your css files where located in a database.